# Memory error scipy interpolate in rectangular array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to use `interp2d` from `Scipy` with the following data:

Shape of x = (1,8645)
Shape of y = (1,4335)

Shape of data = (4335,8654)

This is what I've tried:

```
ix=interpolate.interpd2d(x,y,data)
ip=ix(10.25,56.77)
```

I received error like this :

> nx, tx, ny, ty, c, fp, ier = dfitpack.regrid_smth x, y, z, None, None,
>   None, None, kx=kx, ky=ky, s=0.0)self.tck = (tx[:nx], ty[:ny], c[:(nx -
>   kx - 1) * (ny - ky - 1)], kx, ky)
>
> MemoryError:

How can I resolve this issue ?

I have found one option for slicing the array into small bits, but it also doesn't work. This only works for a square array.

```
def my_interp(X, Y, Z, x, y, spn=3):
    xs,ys = map(np.array,(x,y))
    print xs.shape
    z = np.zeros(xs.shape)
    for i,(x,y) in enumerate(zip(xs,ys)):
        # get the indices of the nearest x,y
        xi = np.argmin(np.abs(X[0,:]-x))
        yi = np.argmin(np.abs(Y[:,0]-y))
        xlo = max(xi-spn, 0)
        ylo = max(yi-spn, 0)
        xhi = min(xi+spn, X[0,:].size)
        yhi = min(yi+spn, Y[:,0].size)
        # make slices of X,Y,Z that are only a few items wide
        nX = X[xlo:xhi, ylo:yhi]
        nY = Y[xlo:xhi, ylo:yhi]
        nZ = Z[xlo:xhi, ylo:yhi]
        intp = interpolate.interp2d(nX, nY, nZ)
        z[i] = intp(x,y)[0]
    return z
```

Comment: Are you using a Python version of 32 or 64 bits?

Comment: I am using Python 32 bit

Comment: What I have recently noticed is that when I use 64bit of Python, there is no such error. So is there a way to make it work in 32 bit also..

Comment: You could build an algorithm that would make your operation in sections but never have your entire sections loaded into memory. This would depend a lot on the problem. The most reasonable solution is really update to Python 64. Use a package that already brings everything prepared automatically like WinPython or Anaconda.